# How to execute a script on a server from a webpage?

Tags: php, shell, cgi, vps, cgi-bin

I want to run a shell script off my VPS through a website to start and stop a service. I have a script i currently execute by puttying in and typing ctf.sh. I had a look at using CGI and stuff, however this has left me thoroughly confused.
On my VPS my web folder is ofcourse /var/www so where would i find the cgi-bin folder and how would i go about runing such things? Sorry for such a stupid question :S

Answer (score 4):

You could execute your script like:

```
exec('/path/to/your/script.sh');
```